# ImageView, selector and on-click, on-long-click

Tags: selector, android-imageview, onlongclicklistener

I have some `ImageView`'s:

The selector for right arrow button is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="3" android:state_pressed="true"/> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:drawable="1" android:state_enabled="false"/> <!-- enabled -->
    <item android:drawable="2"/> <!-- default -->

</selector>
```

(`1`, `2`, `3` look like the ones in the picture below — `1` is for left arrow button, but the right's one looks like the same with opposite direction).

[image]

Now my problem is:

1. When the user does click, I use `setEnable()` to change its status. It works.
2. When the user does long click, again, I use `setEnable()` to change its status. But after the user released his finger, the button retains status as image `#3`.
3. I tried: [`cancelLongPress()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#cancelLongPress()), [`clearFocus()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#clearFocus()), [`invalidate()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate()), [`post(Runnable)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#post(java.lang.Runnable)), [`postInvalidate()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#postInvalidate()), [`refreshDrawableState()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#refreshDrawableState())… but they didn't work.

The app uses minimum SDK 4 (Android 1.6). Could you help me?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Temporary solution:

```
...
imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            v.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    v.setEnabled(...);
                }// run()
            }, 200); // 200 ms is enough
        }

        return false;
    }// onTouch()
});
```